# Is there a way to plot markers on a specific date on a TimeSliderChoropleth map using folium?

Tags: python, mapping, data-visualization, geojson, folium

I currently have a TimeSliderChoropleth map working with the number of Covid-19 cases as the time series element. I'm wondering is there any way to add markers on a specific date using folium? Say I want to show that on the 16th March the UK went into lockdown and then left it in June or similar.

I've tried doing it this way:

```
folium.GeoJson('file').add_to(worldMap)
```

This just maps all the points from the get-go and never plots it from the time specified. Is there any way to do what I'm after or not?